# How to convert coding to C++ from C?

Tags: c++, c

void main(){

```
   char name [50];
   int id;
   int year;
   float salary;
   float bonus;

     printf(" PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME : ");
     scanf("%c",&name);
     printf("\n");

     printf(" PLEASE ENTER YOUR ID: ");
     scanf("%d",&id);
     printf("\n");

     printf(" ENTER AMOUNT OF YEARS YOU HAVE WORKED: ");
     scanf("%d",&year);
     printf("\n");

    printf(" ENTER YOUR MONTHLY SALARY: ");
    scanf("%f",&salary);
    printf("\n");


    if(year<5)
    bonus=1000;

    else if((year>5)&&(year<10))
    bonus=0.02*(salary)+1000;

    else if (year >10){
    bonus=0.03*(salary)+1000;
    }
    printf("YOUR BONUS IS:",bonus);

    printf("/n");
    printf("/n");
    printf("/n");


    printf("***CSC COMPANY ***\n");
    printf("NAME : ",name);
    printf("ID : ",id);
    printf("YEARS OF SERVICES: ",year);
    printf("MONTHLY SALARY (RM): ",salary);
    printf("BONUS(RM): ",bonus);

    getch();
    }
```

That's the coding I received and I really need help converting it to C++. Please help me out. I'm very poor at converting programs from C to C++ even though I know that the program is relatively simple and basic. So, if anyone could help me with this, it would be very much appreciated. Also, if anyone could tell me how to get any C and C++ program for windows 8.1 that would be awesome too.

Comment: Change `void main()` to `int main()`, remove `getch()`, and `#include <stdio.h>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your C code there is a fault: To take input name you have to use ***scanf("%s",&name)*** instead of ***%c***.
To convert the code into C++,you just have to use ***cin & cout***.Though it is allowed to use scanf & printf in c++.I have use string instead of char array....here is the sample code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string name;
   int id;
   int year;
   float salary;
   float bonus;

   cout<<" PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME : ";
   cin>>name;
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<" PLEASE ENTER YOUR ID: ";
   cin>>id;
   cout<<"\n";

 cout<<" ENTER AMOUNT OF YEARS YOU HAVE WORKED: ";
 cin>>year;
 cout<<"\n";

  cout<<" ENTER YOUR MONTHLY SALARY: ";
  cin>>salary;
  cout<<"\n";

  if(year<5)
  bonus=1000;

  else if((year>5)&&(year<10))
  bonus=0.02*(salary)+1000;

  else if (year >10){
  bonus=0.03*(salary)+1000;
 }
 cout<<"YOUR BONUS IS:"<<bonus;

 cout<<"/n";
 cout<<"/n";
 cout<<"/n";


cout<<"***CSC COMPANY ***\n";
cout<<"NAME : "<<name;
cout<<"ID : "<<id;
cout<<"YEARS OF SERVICES: "<<year;
cout<<"MONTHLY SALARY (RM): "<<salary;
cout<<"BONUS(RM): "<<bonus;

 getch();
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
void main(){
```

`void main` has never been valid in either language, so right off that tells you that this is not the highest quality code.

Use standard `int main()`, or in C++11 syntax, if you standardize on that, `auto main() -> int`.

---

```
char name [50];
```

In C++ use `std::string` for narrow text string variables.

---

```
float salary;
float bonus;
```

By default use `double` not `float`. For example, the type of `3.14` is `double`, not `float`. Using `float` is a way to save memory and in some contexts increase speed, at the cost of reduced number of significant digits (and potentially also *reduced* speed, due to conversion to/from `double`).

`float` can be good for beginners working in C, because `scanf` with a simple `%f` needs `float`. There is no such reason in C++, when using C++ isotreams.

---

```
 printf(" PLEASE ENTER YOUR NAME : ");
 scanf("%c",&name)
```

The `scanf` call here is a bug.

In C++ programs like this just use the more type safe `cout` and `cin` iostreams. Output via operator `<<`.  For names without spaces you can use operator `>>` input, but I would recommend changing this to line input, `getline`.

---

```
getch();
```

Stopping at the end of the program is not a solution to anything: it's only a problem. So remove this.

To see all the output, either run the program from a command interpreter, or e.g. in Visual Studio run it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, or in a debugger place a breakpoint on the final right brace of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get this C code?

It contains **many** errors and invokes undefined behavior for people with exactly 5 or 10 years of working time.  It would be quite risky to rely on the answer produced by this program to write bonus checks!

After you fix the C version, converting it to C++ is simple: just compiling it with the C++ compiler will do.  I you need to convert this to a full blown Windows interactive application using C++, you are in the wrong place.  If you just want to use C++ specific input/output streams, look into the `<<` overloaded operator.